# Assembly not being loaded from mkbundle'd executable

Tags: mono, servicestack, gac, mkbundle

I'm mkbundling a bunch of assemblies, including ServiceStack.Text. When running mkbundle, it tells me it's being embedded:

```
embedding: /home/user/Verisys/build/ServiceStack.Text.dll
```

However, when I try to run the resulting executable, I get this:

```
Unhandled exception
System.ApplicationException: RootDir '/opt/mono32/lib/mono/gac/ServiceStack.Text/4.0.0.0__e06fbc6124f57c43' for virtual path does not exist
  at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualPathProvider.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualPathProvider..ctor (IAppHost appHost, System.IO.DirectoryInfo rootDirInfo) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.VirtualPath.FileSystemVirtualPathProvider..ctor (IAppHost appHost, System.String rootDirectoryPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MyExe.OnStart (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any idea why it is attempting to load this assembly from the GAC, instead of using the embedded one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug with how ServiceStack is picking up `WebHostPhysicalPath`. You may be able to resolve this yourself by manually specifying the root directory of your application in the `Configure` method of your `AppHost`:

```cs
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    Config = new HostConfig {
        WebHostPhysicalPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks! I would never have picked up on that myself!

Comment: It did not fix my problem. I still have the same issue. Any other answers?

Comment: @DeeJay' If you are having a problem then create your own question and provide details of the steps you have taken, and the issue that is occurring.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I got it solved by upgrading the .net framework (I do not actually remember the version, but its a minor release in the same 4.0) Anyway my problem was the same as described in the question.